# How to hide / disable / non-clickable MenuBarExtra in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to **hide/disable** `MenuBarExtra` in SwiftUI for a MacOS application. Can anyone please suggest to me on how to hide my `MenuBarExtra`?

```
@main
struct UtilityApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
     // how do I hide/disable/non-clickable this?
        MenuBarExtra {
            Button("One") {}
            Button("Two") {}
            Button("Three") {}
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "repeat.circle.fill")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: img1]

---

Unsatisfactory attempts to solve

by hiding  the `label` of `MenuBarExtra` but failing to **disable** the MenuBarExtra on click.

```
@main
struct UtilityApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
     // how do I hide/disable/non-clickable this?
        MenuBarExtra {
            Button("One") {}
            Button("Two") {}
            Button("Three") {}
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "repeat.circle.fill")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .hidden() // ⬅️ hiding the lable
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 2):

[The docs say that, since macOS 13, you can control visibility of MenuBarExtra using the parameter `isInserted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra/init(_:isinserted:content:)-6t4ml)

```
@main
struct AppWithMenuBarExtra: App {
    @AppStorage("showMenuBarExtra") private var showMenuBarExtra = true


    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra(
            "App Menu Bar Extra", systemImage: "star",
            isInserted: $showMenuBarExtra)
        {
            StatusMenu()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I found an okay  solution but not perfect!!!

Warning ⚠️: It's not a perfect solution because it still reserves space on the status bar. You have to click on the `MenuBarExtra` to notice it.

I am trying to hide both the **lable** and the **content** of `MenuBarExtra`.

```
@main
struct UtilityApp: App {
    @State var isMenuBarExtraHidden: Bool = false
    var body: some Scene {
     // how do I hide/disable/non-clickable this?
        MenuBarExtra {
            contentForMenuBar()
                .isHidden(isMenuBarExtraHidden) // ⬅️ hiding the content
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "repeat.circle.fill")
                .bold()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .isHidden(isMenuBarExtraHidden) // ⬅️ hiding the lable
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func contentForMenuBar() -> some View {
        Button("One") {}
        Button("Two") {}
        Button("Three") {}
    }
}
```

---

I added an extension for the `View` type.

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool, remove: Bool = false) -> some View {
        if hidden {
            if !remove {
                self.hidden()
            }
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MenuBarExtraAccess](https://github.com/orchetect/MenuBarExtraAccess) package to show/hide your `MenuBarExtra`.
It uses introspection (`Mirror`) to get to access to `NSStatusBarItem` where you could use its property `isVisible`.

```
import SwiftUI
import MenuBarExtraAccess

@main
struct SO_menuBarExtraHideApp: App {
    @State var isMenuPresented: Bool = false
    @State var isMenuVisible: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Button("Show Menu") { isMenuPresented = true }
            Toggle("Menu bar active", isOn: $isMenuVisible)
        }
        
        MenuBarExtra("MyApp Menu", systemImage: "star") {
            Button("Menu Item 1") { print("Menu Item 1") }
            Button("Menu Item 2") { print("Menu Item 2") }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.menu)
        .menuBarExtraAccess(isPresented: $isMenuPresented) { statusItem in
                statusItem.isVisible = isMenuVisible
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did come across this but I am looking for something that is native rather than adding a package.